# Why can my Mac charge my iPad but other computers can't?

Tags: ipad, usb, charging, power

What do Macs do differently so its USB ports can charge my iPad, but if I plug into a USB port on my PC I get the "not charging" message?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the iPad needs more than the 500 mA that the USB 2.0 spec says computers need to provide.  Macwork has [more information.](http://www.macworld.com/article/150356/2010/04/ipadcharging.html)

Answer (score 8):

Apple's newer machines (and some newer PCs I believe) have got USB ports that are able to provide more current. The following Apple KB article explain better:

- [iPad: Charging the battery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4060)
- [Powering Apple and third party peripherals through USB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4049?viewlocale=en_US)