# How to charge iPad (v1) on a Windows device

Tags: ipad, windows, battery, charging

I have an iPad (first revision) and want to charge it using my Windows laptop. It doesn't want to charge and I've read quite a lot about it now ([this one here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9019/why-can-my-mac-charge-my-ipad-but-other-computers-cant) amongst others via Google), but I haven't found a complete working answer.

**Edit:** I'm not so much interested in the *why*. But more in a practical solution, preferably without any hardware costs. Can someone give a HowTo on charging an iPad on Windows devices?

Comment: Hm. Many external HDDs (w/o PSU) use an USB cable that has 1 male for the device and 2 males for the computer. Usually plugging just one into the computer is enough, but if one port doesn't provide enough power, the second plug will boost the connection with power from another USB port. I wonder: could a similar cable be used in the same fashion with an iPad & PC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An insufficiently-powered USB port *will* charge an iPad, just slower than a high-powered one.

When you plug the USB cable into your laptop the iPad will say "Not Charging." However, when the screen is off it is in fact charging. As soon as you turn the screen on again the battery area will say "Not Charging," too, but again, with the screen off it will charge.

Test it yourself: before plugging in the cable check the battery percentage. Then plug it in and leave the iPad off for 30 minutes; when you turn the screen back on you'll see that the percentage has increased.

In my case it takes several hours to charge from 50% to 100%, but at least it's charging.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I've just noticed this! Is there anything more that can be done to improve the speed of charging? Some places say to have the computer in hibernate, or sleep, or something else again. But they are unclear about which method helps, and some even unclear about if you should put the iPad to sleep / turn it off, or the computer.

Comment: @Lode I don't think any change to the *laptop* will affect things at all, as it's likely that the power coming out of the USB port likely runs at a steady maximum regardless of its state. Shutting the iPad off, however, will undoubtedly help it charge more quickly: press and hold the power button (top of the iPad) until the red "Slide to power off" screen appears and then slide it. It should be using virtually no power at that point, so won't be working against the total charge.

Comment: A PC will only put out 500ma of power regardless of configuration, operating system, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your iPad won't charge when connected to your Windows laptop, the most likely reason is because the USB port you are using doesn't provide enough power for the job.

MacBooks in the last several years are designed to provide sufficient power via USB, but I can't comment on your Windows machine. Sounds like that USB port you are using simply doesn't provide enough power to charge the iPad.

There's no real practical and easy "fix" for this on a laptop. See if the USB port outputs more power when you plug-in the laptop to the wall… though it's unlikely…

Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

An update of the motherboard is necessary. Gigabyte, MSI, and ASUS have issued updates.

[Source: Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2010/05/31/gigabyte-asus-and-msi-deliver-driver-software-to-allow-ipad-cha/)

Comment: Sounds interesting. But I don't see any link to official sources of the manufacturers.. Only found this scary looking website from Asus: http://event.asus.com/mb/2010/ai_charger/

Comment: Might seem scary, but this is what you are looking for. It's just an update.

Answer (score 0):

You need a high power USB port which can provides a 1100 mA output.

Or you can install **[ASUS AI Charger](http://event.asus.com/mb/2010/ai_charger/)** on your device, to tune your USB port to have high power output.